# Using Feeds (module) how to attach more than one feed per node?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-feeds

I'm using the [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) module, but I am looiking for the functionality the [Feedfield](http://drupal.org/project/feedfield) module provides: declare multiple feeds on a single node, and have a parser generate the nodes from the feeds. Problem is Feedfield uses the core Aggregator, and I need Feeds functionality.

Can I reproduce such a behaviour with Feeds and any addon? How?

Comment: someone with 'create tag' powers, please tag this question 'drupal-feeds'

Comment: you asked for it, you got it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it can't be done right now. There is a [issue](http://drupal.org/node/634462) that will eventually lead to development of such functionality, but right now, no can do.